# Viewing/Drilling down .NET Profiler Trace in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

Sometimes on occasions one of the app service instances generates high CPU or Memory usage.
It is caused by the Method() within a MVC application. This method contains multiple lines of code and at this moment it is hard to track what line of the code is actually causing an issues.  Downloaded.NET profiler Trace straight from the troubled instance and loaded into the Visual Studio. Created a detailed report and sorted the function names based on the total CPU usage, identified the main method that is taking the most time to process.

Question: Is there a way for me to identify in the profile trace detail report what line of code is actually causing the issue (with my MVC project open in the solution as well) ?

In the snapshot, i can see on the right side that generic list constructor is taking the most time to process, any way for me to find what specific line of code in the ProcessXML() method is causing the issue ? We have lots of generic list instantiations in that method and it would be nice to get to the line of code itself, is it possible with Visual Studio and the downloaded profile trace ?

Any leads documentation would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017, I have tried to log the traces using profiler.

Iam trying to retrieve the `Connection String` value which is not set.

- In `Global.asax` file I wrote the below line of code to log and trace the error.

```cs
string conn=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ToString();
```

***Start the profiler.***

In `Visual Studio` => `Debug` => click on `Performance Profiler`.

[image]

- Select the Target and click on start.
- Select the required method.

[image]

- Select your Project.
  [image]
- Run the Application.
- Stop the profiler.
  In the `Call Tree` Iam able to see that `Global.asax` file is logged with `GetConnectionString`.

[image]

- Expand the window and you will see an option to download the error.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i am working with a .NET Profile Trace that i pulled from Azure's Diagnostic Tool at the time when CPU spike occurred. I would like to match the processes in the report to the location in the .NET MVC project that is causing an issue.